# How to remove Cinnamon's Alt-F1 keybinding using Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I've just started using Linux Mint 15 with Cinnamon 1.8.8 at work and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> the display zoom out and displays the workspace switcher.

How can I disable this shortcut? I removed the keyboard shortcuts in System settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts that seemed relevant but with no effect. Then I removed all of them, but of course still no effect.

**Update**
The accepted answer worked for Mint 15. After upgrading to Mint 16 I also had to use dconf-editor as described by [maosmurf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53770/maosmurf) below.

Comment: Maybe you need to log out and in again to change it effectively.

Comment: Tried to log out and back in. The Alt-F1 keybinding is still there.

Comment: You can possibly remove the keybinding by first running `xev`, then pressing Alt+F1, and then look at section `keycode` in the output. Then run the command: `xmodmap -e "keycode # = """`, where # is the keycode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system (Cinnamon 1.8.8 on Linux Mint Debian Edition) I can disable it in the Gnome control center. Open a terminal and run `gnome-control-center`:

[image]

Go into `keyboard` => Shortcuts and select the `System` section on the left:

[image]

Now, change the shortcut for "Show the activities overview" click on it and then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable it.

---

It may be possible to do the same on Linux Mint 15 by going into `cinnamon-control-center` but that is [not available](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=218&t=138457) on the Debian edition so I can't check.

Comment: I installed gnome-control-center with apt-get and it worked fine. Thanks! Strange that the Cinnamon settings doesn't show the "Show the activities overview" setting.

Answer (score 9):

Under Linux Mint 16 "Petra" Cinnamon, I had a similar problem.
Removing the Keyboard shortcuts under `gnome-control-center` and `cinnamon-control-center` had no effect.
Solution that worked for me:

- run `dconf-editor`
- navigate to `org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings`
- for `panel-main-menu`, replace `['<Alt>F1']` with `[]`
- logout & login

(props to [Nick Fortescue @ Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/531874/disable-alt-f1-keyboard-shortcut-in-cinnamon))

Comment: After upgrading to Mint 16, I had to do this too. Thanks.

Comment: After upgrading to Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, I had to remove ALT-F1 again. This time under System Settings / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts / General / Toggle Expo (double click into "ALT-F1" and hit backspace)
Now my IDE is happy again :)

Comment: Thanks so much. The Find function in dconf-editor is not capable of finding F1 in arrays o.O An alternative to switch off the shortcut is this shell command: `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-to-workspace-up '["<Ctrl><Alt>Up"]'`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Had to `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` first.

Comment: "double click into ... and hit backspace" wow, that is not even close to intuitive! Should be able to just select the entry and hit delete/backspace.