# How to disable ALT + HOME shortcut? Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

My notebook keyboard seems pressing random times the shortcut ALT + Home. Is bad because when I'm in, e.g., browser, I go to home page.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
Go into keyboard => Shortcuts and select the System section on the left
```

Option 2:

```
run dconf-editor
navigate to org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings
for panel-main-menu, replace ['<Alt>F4'] with []
logout & login
```

Refer post : [How to remove Cinnamon's Alt-F1 keybinding using Linux Mint 15](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99195/how-to-remove-cinnamons-alt-f1-keybinding-using-linux-mint-15)